# Optaplanner core dump @ ConditionEvaluator504f0cef2aeb46d49c660e07bfa907fd.evaluate

Tags: spring-boot, drools, optaplanner

I'm getting a core dump from an Optaplanner web app using Spring Boot, with the message:

```
============== DEBUG MESSAGE: illegal bytecode sequence - method not verified ================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x00000251502459dd, pid=15424, tid=0x0000000000004250
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  ConditionEvaluator504f0cef2aeb46d49c660e07bfa907fd.evaluate(Lorg/drools/core/common/InternalFactHandle;Lorg/drools/core/common/InternalWorkingMemory;Lorg/drools/core/spi/Tuple;)Z+9
#

It looks like something to do with class loading, but I tried removing spring-boot-devtools from the pom file and it didn't help.
```

I'm using:
Optaplanner version: 7.40.0.Final

Spring Boot: 2.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: I haven't seen issue in drools-core this yet, normally drools 7.x works fine on JDK 1.8, thousdands of users use it in that circumstances.

Comment: spring-boot-devtools has been known to cause issues with ClassLoaders, but that's usually solved by using the optaplanner spring boot starter (or using overloaded create() methods that accept a classloader).

Comment: I am still struggling to solve a comparable problem. What platform are you experiencing this error on? I am experiencing an error like this but only when running on windows. Interestingly Drools 6.4.0-FINAL and Drools 7.2.0-FINAL both have this problem. I am able to reproduce it on different windows computers. When running on the same computers but from within a Linux Centos VM the problem does not occur. Unfortunately, currently I can only reproduce it when running long batch processes and I haven't yet been able to identify the piece of drools code that causes it.

Comment: @Edvaaart for me the fix was to use classes instead of primitives (Integer vs int, etc.) in the planning facts.

Comment: thanks @elk-tamer, I will try that and post a comment about my results

Comment: @elk-tamer - better late than never - I never managed to successfully implement your suggestion. However, today we managed to close in on the culprit by moving to Drools 7.x which enables us to get some more detail in exceptions being thrown. We were still using a Boolean in one of the methods called from a rule. Replacing it with the boolean primitive solved it. No crashes on windows anymore. I suspect that under very specific circumstances drools seems to have a problem combining primitives and objects. Still no clue about the details unfortunately. But at least my problem seems gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `mvn dependency:tree` or find another way to list all jars in your classpath.

All dependencies/jars starting with optaplanner, drools and kie should be the same version (7.40.0.Final in your case).

Comment: Thank for the reply Ge0ffrey, I get this,    [INFO] +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-spring-boot-starter:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-jackson:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-common:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-test:jar:7.41.0.Final:compile

Comment: so I don't think that's the problem,  but it's good to know it's not a known problem. I might be trying to use the SolverManager class incorrrectly. I'm going to copy the code from the newish web example and see if that works. If I find the actual cause, even it's something silly I was doing, I'll post it.

Comment: In theory, no java program should be able to cause a core dump.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what's causing this? This is scary. JDK core dumps are in theory impossible. The only thing I can think off is that the Drools ASM generation and/or the spring Boot devtools magic cause a bytecode generating and/or classloading issue.

Comment: I haven't found the cause, but I have a "workaround" ,which is probably the correct way to handle it anyway. I'll answer my question so I can use formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The crash was happening only when I used certain rules in a drl for a NurseRostering type of planning problem.

This version of the rule causes the crash:

```
rule "selfScheduleOnly"
    when
        $assignment : ShiftAssignmentO(                                     
            employee != null, $employee : employee,  employee.isSelfScheduled(),
            $shift : shift)
        not $shiftOnRequest : ShiftRequestO(employee == $employee, shift == $shift )
    then
         scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);                  
end
```

This version does not:

```
rule "selfScheduleOnly"
    when
        $employee : EmployeeO(isSelfScheduled())
        $assignment : ShiftAssignmentO(                                      
            $employee == employee,  
            $shift : shift)
        not $shiftOnRequest : ShiftRequestO(employee == $employee, shift == $shift )
    then
         scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);                  
end
```

I recall reading that score corruption could be caused by referencing a property pointing to a fact instead of a direct reference to a fact, so it sort of makes sense. I haven't tried every combination, but it seemed to only be happening when the property being checked was a Boolean.

Comment: Can you share with us a reproducer to let us fix the JVM crash problem? File a bug on issues.redhat.com Thank you!